# Jumblers vs Rebuilders: Coding with Tetris Bricks - Area for Rebuilder Answers

Tags: cops-and-robbers

This is the companion question to [Jumblers vs Rebuilders: Coding with Tetris Bricks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/jumblers-vs-rebuilders-coding-with-tetris-bricks) where Rebuilders can post their solutions.

As argued in [Where should we put robbers?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/where-should-we-put-robbers) it allows more formatting freedom for robbers and lets them gain rep.

Only answer this question if you have cracked a yet uncracked answer to [Jumblers vs Rebuilders: Coding with Tetris Bricks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/jumblers-vs-rebuilders-coding-with-tetris-bricks). **Please include a link to that answer in your answer *and* a comment in that answer linking to your answer.**

The accepted answer for this question will be the winning rebuilder.

The scoreboard will only appear in the [other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/jumblers-vs-rebuilders-coding-with-tetris-bricks).

[COTO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31019/coto) has generously made [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjfmyzqg/1/) for easily manipulating code-bricks. I've [updated this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CalvinsHobbies/jgz3z53z/) so ES 6 is not required, and minimized it for this Stack Snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>function parseSpec(s){function first(){var e,t;t=S.findIndex(function(t){return(e=t.findIndex(function(e){return/\S/.test(e)}))!=-1});return t==-1?null:[e,t]}function at(e){var t=e[0],n=e[1];return n>=0&&n<S.length&&t>=0&&t<S[n].length?S[n][t]:" "}function wipe(e){var t=e[0],n=e[1];if(n>=0&&n<S.length&&t>=0&&t<S[n].length)S[n][t]=" "}var P,S=s.split("\n").map(function(e){return e.split("")});var oPats=$(".proto-tet [pat]").get().map(function(e){return{sPat:eval("["+$(e).attr("pat")+"]"),e:e,block:function(e){return[at(e)].concat(this.sPat.map(function(t){return at([e[0]+t[0],e[1]+t[1]])}))},wipe:function(e){this.sPat.forEach(function(e){return wipe([P[0]+e[0],P[1]+e[1]])})},match:function(e){return!/\s/.test(this.block(e).join(""))}}});window.oPats=oPats;while(P=first()){var oPat=oPats.find(function(e){return e.match(P)});if(!oPat){orphan(at(P));wipe(P);continue}createPiece(oPat.e,oPat.block(P));wipe(P);oPat.wipe(P)}}function createPiece(e,t){function r(e){var t=$(this).position();G.isIgnoreClick=false;G.eDrag=this;G.iOffsets=[e.clientX-t.left,e.clientY-t.top]}function i(){if(G.isIgnoreClick)return;var e=$(this);s($(".proto-tet ."+e.attr("rr")),function(e,t){return n[t-1]},e.css("left"),e.css("top"));e.remove()}function s(e,t,n,s){e.clone().html(e.html().replace(/@(\d)(\d)/g,t)).appendTo("body").on("mousedown",r).click(i).css({left:n,top:s})}var n=[];s($(e),function(e,r,i){return n[r-1]=t[i-1]},18+G.iSpawn%8*18*4+"px",18+~~(G.iSpawn/8)*18*4+"px");G.iSpawn++}function init(){$(document).on("mouseup",function(){return G.eDrag=null}).on("mousemove",function(e){if(G.eDrag){var t=$(G.eDrag),n=Math.round((e.clientX-G.iOffsets[0])/18)*18,r=Math.round((e.clientY-G.iOffsets[1])/18)*18,i=t.position();if(n!=i.left||r!=i.top)G.isIgnoreClick=true;t.css({left:n+"px",top:r+"px"})}})}function orphan(e){error("Spec character not a part of any block: '"+e+"'")}function error(e){$(".error").css("display","block").append("<div>"+e+"</div>")}function go(){$(init);$(function(){parseSpec($("#spec").val())});$("#spec").remove();$("#info").remove();$("#go").remove()}var G={eDrag:null,isIgnoreClick:true,iSpawn:0};Array.prototype.findIndex=function(e){for(var t=0;t<this.length;t++){if(e(this[t]))return t}return-1};Array.prototype.find=function(e){var t=this.findIndex(e);if(t==-1)return;else return this[t]}</script><style>.proto-tet, .spec{display: none;}.tet-I{color: darkgreen;}.tet-J{color: orangered;}.tet-L{color: navy;}.tet-T{color: darkred;}.tet-O{color: darkcyan;}.tet-S{color: darkviolet;}.tet-Z{color: darkorange;}body > .tet{position: absolute;cursor: move;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;border-collapse: collapse;}.tet td{width: 18px;height: 18px;font: bold 14px "Courier New",monospace;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;padding: 0;}.error{z-index: 1024;position: absolute;display: none;color: red;font-weight: bold;background-color: white;}textarea{font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;}</style><div id='info'>Put code-bricks here and hit OK. Re-run the snippet to restart.<br>(You may need to replace spaces in code-bricks with some other character first.)</div><textarea id='spec' rows='16' cols='80'>ABCD&nbsp;&nbsp;a&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Oo&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;c&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;oo&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;d&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&nbsp;E&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;h&#13;&#10;&nbsp;F&nbsp;&nbsp;efg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;GFE&#13;&#10;&nbsp;GH&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;f&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;H&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;e&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;&nbsp;I&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IJK&#13;&#10;&nbsp;J&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;l&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;L&#13;&#10;LK&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;kji&nbsp;&nbsp;kl&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;j&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;i&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;t&#13;&#10;&nbsp;OP&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;p&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;QR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;rs&#13;&#10;MN&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;on&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ST&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;q&#13;&#10;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;m&#13;&#10;&nbsp;W&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;z&#13;&#10;&nbsp;XY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;zxw&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;yx&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Y&#13;&#10;&nbsp;Z&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;y&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;w&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;WXZ</textarea><br><button id='go' type='button' onclick='go()'>OK</button><div class="proto-tet"><table class="tet tet-I tet-I0" rr="tet-I1" pat="[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]"><tr><td>@11</td><td>@22</td><td>@33</td><td>@44</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-I tet-I1" rr="tet-I2" pat="[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]"><tr><td>@11</td></tr><tr><td>@22</td></tr><tr><td>@33</td></tr><tr><td>@44</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-I tet-I2" rr="tet-I3" ><tr><td>@40</td><td>@30</td><td>@20</td><td>@10</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-I tet-I3" rr="tet-I0"><tr><td>@40</td></tr><tr><td>@30</td></tr><tr><td>@20</td></tr><tr><td>@10</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-J tet-J0" rr="tet-J1" pat="[0,1],[-1,2],[0,2]"><tr><td></td><td>@11</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@22</td></tr><tr><td>@33</td><td>@44</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-J tet-J1" rr="tet-J2" pat="[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]"><tr><td>@31</td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@42</td><td>@23</td><td>@14</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-J tet-J2" rr="tet-J3" pat="[1,0],[0,1],[0,2]"><tr><td>@41</td><td>@32</td></tr><tr><td>@23</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@14</td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-J tet-J3" rr="tet-J0" pat="[1,0],[2,0],[2,1]"><tr><td>@11</td><td>@22</td><td>@43</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td>@34</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-O tet-O0" rr="tet-O1" pat="[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]"><tr><td>@11</td><td>@22</td></tr><tr><td>@33</td><td>@44</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-O tet-O1" rr="tet-O2"><tr><td>@30</td><td>@10</td></tr><tr><td>@40</td><td>@20</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-O tet-O2" rr="tet-O3"><tr><td>@40</td><td>@30</td></tr><tr><td>@20</td><td>@10</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-O tet-O3" rr="tet-O0"><tr><td>@20</td><td>@40</td></tr><tr><td>@10</td><td>@30</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-L tet-L0" rr="tet-L1" pat="[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]"><tr><td>@11</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@22</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@33</td><td>@44</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-L tet-L1" rr="tet-L2" pat="[1,0],[2,0],[0,1]"><tr><td>@31</td><td>@22</td><td>@13</td></tr><tr><td>@44</td><td></td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-L tet-L2" rr="tet-L3" pat="[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]"><tr><td>@41</td><td>@32</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@23</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@14</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-L tet-L3" rr="tet-L0" pat="[-2,1],[-1,1],[0,1]"><tr><td></td><td></td><td>@41</td></tr><tr><td>@12</td><td>@23</td><td>@34</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-S tet-S0" rr="tet-S1" pat="[1,0],[-1,1],[0,1]"><tr><td></td><td>@21</td><td>@12</td></tr><tr><td>@43</td><td>@34</td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-S tet-S1" rr="tet-S2" pat="[0,1],[1,1],[1,2]"><tr><td>@41</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@32</td><td>@23</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@14</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-S tet-S2" rr="tet-S3"><tr><td></td><td>@30</td><td>@40</td></tr><tr><td>@10</td><td>@20</td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-S tet-S3" rr="tet-S0"><tr><td>@10</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@20</td><td>@30</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@40</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-Z tet-Z0" rr="tet-Z1" pat="[1,0],[1,1],[2,1]"><tr><td>@11</td><td>@22</td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@33</td><td>@44</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-Z tet-Z1" rr="tet-Z2" pat="[-1,1],[0,1],[-1,2]"><tr><td></td><td>@11</td></tr><tr><td>@32</td><td>@23</td></tr><tr><td>@44</td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-Z tet-Z2" rr="tet-Z3"><tr><td>@40</td><td>@30</td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@20</td><td>@10</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-Z tet-Z3" rr="tet-Z0"><tr><td></td><td>@40</td></tr><tr><td>@20</td><td>@30</td></tr><tr><td>@10</td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-T tet-T0" rr="tet-T1" pat="[1,0],[2,0],[1,1]"><tr><td>@11</td><td>@22</td><td>@33</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@44</td><td></td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-T tet-T1" rr="tet-T2" pat="[-1,1],[0,1],[0,2]"><tr><td></td><td>@11</td></tr><tr><td>@42</td><td>@23</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>@34</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-T tet-T2" rr="tet-T3" pat="[-1,1],[0,1],[1,1]"><tr><td></td><td>@41</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@32</td><td>@23</td><td>@14</td></tr></table><table class="tet tet-T tet-T3" rr="tet-T0" pat="[0,1],[1,1],[0,2]"><tr><td>@31</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>@22</td><td>@43</td></tr><tr><td>@14</td><td></td></tr></table></div><div class="error"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Crack of xnor's [340-area answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40146/30688)

No cryptographic mumbo-jumbo for me.

**Code:**

```
10000001111111222
22388892357889356
69968999352143221
80867227952780811
a=23333333444444
b=71122368066667
c=47948316823798
d=79254432699451 
496857235742     
579159386011     
606961806231     
pow(a,b,c)-d     
62656269644465648
67766884711672530
73487440752777431
print('Tetris'*(1
))               
7873806482918808 
8843930593249458 
946095869869
```

**Mapping of blocks to line numbers**

```
    #Four spaces 9-12
    #Four spaces 9-12
    #Four spaces 9-12
    #Four spaces 9-12
    #Four spaces 17
    #Four spaces 17
    #Four spaces 17
    #Four spaces 17-20
    #Four spaces 5-8
))  #Two spaces 17
0290 1-4
0398 1-4
0866 1-4
0887 1-4
0892 1-4
0992 1-4
1108 13-16
1268 1-4
1297 1-4
1339 1-4
1555 1-4
1722 1-4
1817 1-4
1848 1-4
1930 1-4
2328 1-4
2521 1-4
2611 1-4
2747 5-8
3179 5-8
3192 5-8
3245 5-8
3284 5-8
3334 5-8
3613 5-8
3862 5-8
4086 5-8
4629 5-8
4639 5-8
4674 5-8
4695 5-8
4781 5-8
4968 9
5723 9
5742 9
5791 10
5938 10
6011 10
6069 11
6180 11 
6231 11
6265 13
6269 13
6444 13
6564 13
6776 14
6884 14 
7116 14
7253 14
7348 15
7440 15 
7527 15
7743 15
7873 17
8064 17 
8291 17
8808 17
8843 18
9305 18
9324 18
9458 18
9460 19
9586 19
9869 19
==== 5-8
a,b, 12
abcd 5-8
c)-d 12
etri 16
pow( 12
prin 16
s'*( 16
t('T 16
four spaces  9-12
four spaces  20
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution to [xnor's 212 area puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40142/19475)**

```
print('Tetris'* (3580048039607960824098110131314133014381502228523172479258529553116373838184169‌​435643604632480050165153525653945598563157585840631264256539704571638903974876749‌​009825073297156762481649%38941394))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Teromino Sandbox

While not a solution ipso facto, I wanted to share [this online tool](http://jsfiddle.net/bjfmyzqg/1/) I put together with other potential rebuilders. It facilitates quick and error-free manipulation of the "code tetrominos".

The shapes are specified using a simple character grid in the `spec` element. Most answers should be a simple copy/paste off of PPCG. The default shape spec provides numerous examples. I've also included the shape specs for my [C-72](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40140/jumblers-vs-rebuilders-coding-with-tetris-bricks/40198#40198) answer.

Two caveats:

1. the specs are whitespace-sensitive
2. some HTML control characters may need to be escaped

The pieces are shown in different colours. Drag them to move them, and click them to rotate them. Easy peasy.

Anyone who wants to add improvements, add new specs, fix bugs, etc., is welcome to fork the fiddle and edit this answer to provide an updated link.

Happy rebuilding. :)

Comment: Is there something strange I need to do to get this to work? It doesn't do anything for me in any of the three browsers I have installed.

Comment: @Geobits: It does use numerous ES6 features. I'm running it in the latest FF without problems. Let me test it in Chrome.

Comment: Ha! Apparently I don't often update/use Firefox. It was version 22. Latest works fine.

Comment: Chrome 38 seems to be choking on the lambda expressions. I didn't realize it couldn't handle them. :O   IE I knew couldn't handle them, but... who uses IE. :D

Comment: I've made the fiddle compatible with Chrome and put it into a Stack Snippet in the question. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies: Not at all. Thanks for making the fix.

Answer (score 5):

## Solution to es1024's [80 area answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40155/25180)

```
main(q){char c[]
={'/T','$"e','t'
,0162,'rIi>`:i',
'?#>s',q<q/**/};
return puts(c);}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution to [Gerli's 72 area submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40230/8478)

```
FromCharacterCode[
 {8*10+4, 10*10+1,
 100+16, 10*10+14,
 105, 115}]//Print
```

There's a mistake in the submission though. In the third `T` block, Gerli "rotated" the `[` and `{` when rotating the block.

All done by hand. The `Print` was quite easy to find. Then I wrote out the remaining letters, and found them to be an anagram of `FromCharacterCode`. That put a lot of restrictions on the maximum code height and most blocks. Since there was no `@` and only one pair of brackets, that gave away that `Print` was applied using suffix notation (which determined both its position and that it's preceded by the `//`. In the end there were only an `S` and two `T`s left. The `S` was forced by the layout and the first assignment of `T`s I tried worked.